# I can't install puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a problem with install puppeteer.

**I set Visual Code in firewall**

When I write `npm install puppeteer` terminal show me this ERROR :

```
 ERROR: Failed to set up Chromium r869685! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.
Error: Download failed: server returned code 403. URL: https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Win/869685/chrome-win.zip
    at D:\webs\scraper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\node\BrowserFetcher.js:366:27
    at ClientRequest.requestCallback (D:\webs\scraper\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\node\BrowserFetcher.js:492:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:483:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (_http_client.js:647:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:126:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:515:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\webs\scraper\package.json'
npm WARN scraper No description
npm WARN scraper No repository field.
npm WARN scraper No README data

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! puppeteer@9.1.1 install: node install.js
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the puppeteer@9.1.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AA\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-28T13_57_47_494Z-debug.log
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: It looks like google is blocking you. You must have done something pretty bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google is blocking you to download.

Try this :-

set environment variable **PUPPETEER_DOWNLOAD_HOST** to  http://storage.googleapis.com

Comment: tired export PUPPETEER_DOWNLOAD_HOST=http://storage.googleapis.com/ got error  **INFO** Skipping browser download as instructed.
npm ERR! ERROR: Failed to set up Chromium r1045629! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.
npm ERR! Error: Download failed: server returned code 400. URL: http://storage.googleapis.com//chromium-browser-snapshots/Mac/1045629/chrome-mac.zip

Comment: npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-azure-login/node_modules/puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserFetcher.js:444:27
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.requestCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-azure-login/node_modules/puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserFetcher.js:562:13)
npm ERR!     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)

Comment: npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (node:_http_client:693:27)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:117:17)
npm ERR!     at Socket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:534:22)
npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR!     at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
npm ERR!     at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)